# While running multiple automated tests in BrowserStack, first test runs successfully but the sessions doesn't get created for remaining ones

Tags: selenium, cucumber, browserstack

I am running multiple automated tests (Cucumber, Selenium) in BrowserStack. For the first test, the scenario gets executed. However, from the second test onward, no session gets created in BrowserStack and the scenarios fail with the below exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: [browserstack.local] is set to true but local testing through BrowserStack is not connected. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 5.13 seconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
```

As mentioned, this occurs only from the second automated test onward while executing multiple tests; if each of the test is run individually, the problem does not arise.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be an issue with your test execution method. After the first test, the local tunnel connection appears to be destroyed.

The second test does not have an active tunnel and leads to the error message.

I'd recommend tearing down the tunnel once all the sessions complete execution.